# JavaScript tab to make home as default

Tags: javascript, html

how can i make home tab as default on load?

```html
<ul class="tab" onload="openAction(event, 'All')">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'home')">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'generate')">Generate QR</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'report')">Reports</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'condemn')">Condemn Equipments</a></li>
</ul>

and upon clicking a tab

<div id="home" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  My Home

</div>
<div id="generate" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  Generate

</div>
<div id="report" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  My Reports

</div>
<div id="condemn" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  Condemn Equipments

</div>
```

Comment: Provide your code so that we can have. If you are using a framework it should be router to do so

Comment: <ul class="tab" onload="openAction(event, 'All')">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'home')">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'generate')">Generate QR</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'report')">Reports</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'condemn')">Condemn Equipments</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Do you know that  your question is way too abstract? Show your code and development approach in the question description.

Comment: `<ul class="tab" onload="openAction(event, 'home')">`

Comment: Thankyou sir Lawrence that solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a id="hometag" href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'home')">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'generate')">Generate QR</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'report')">Reports</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openAction(event, 'condemn')">Condemn Equipments</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="home" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  My Home

</div>
<div id="generate" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  Generate

</div>
<div id="report" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  My Reports

</div>
<div id="condemn" class="tabcontent" selected="All" background="images/bodybg.jpg">
  Condemn Equipments

</div>

<script>
(function() {
document.getElementById("hometag").click();
})();
</script>
```